# 娘炮 - how do you pronounce this word/phrase?

Tags: vocabulary, pronunciation, swearing

娘 is clearly niang2, but 炮 is a multiple pronunciation character; it can be bao1 or pao2 or pao4 according to the dictionaries I consulted. I tried searching Baidu for "娘炮拼音" but didn't find anything. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't know pronunciations other than pào. Can you show the dictionaries (screenshots, for example) that you have consulted?

Comment: This was in Pleco. I'm using the free version. A quick Baidu produced this: http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/164536391.html

Answer (score 6):

Oh, get you a [Taiwanese news (at 0:18 by the anchor, 0:58 by a student and 1:24, 1:56 by himself)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kr2NPYqqsUg) about that, where it's pronounced as "niáng pào". I can tell that we use this word in mainland China too, here is the [proof](http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNTg5MjE2Nzg0.html).

It refers to a [sissy](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sissy) (a boy that other boys dislike because he prefers doing things that girls enjoy).

Comment: This was the translation for "pussy" on an episode of Walking Dead.

Comment: @aelephant In that case, it may not be the right translation. Pussy can refer to cowardice; 娘炮 is more like feminine behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pao4 (the most common pronunciation)

如法炮製、炮烙 are pao2
炮羊肉 is bao1

- **When pronouced pào, it usually means artillery.**

  鞭炮: firecracker

  炮兵、炮手: artilleryman
- **páo means burn or roast**

  如法炮製 is an idiom, means follow suit.

  炮烙 is a ancient torture (stamp on someone's body with burning iron)
- **And bāo means stir-fry or drying**

  炮羊肉: stir-fry lamb

  炮乾: drying

  but in fact, bāo is not in common use.

Answer (score 0):

It's "niang2 pao4"
The pronunciation "bao1" or "pao2" of "炮" rarely used.